# Calling a function at a changing rate according to a ease function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have the ability to run functions at a certain rate, which can increase or decrease according to a mathematical function such as a curve... much the same way easing functions like `easeIn` and `easeOut` work in CSS and JQuery.

Here's a crude illustration of an "easeInOut" type scenario. The line represents time, the `o`s a function call.

`o-o--o---o-----o----------o-----o---o--o-o`

Implementation could look something like:

```
trigger(5000, "easeInOut", callback); // Over five seconds, "callback()" is called with an easeInOut ease.

function triggerWithEase(duration, ease, callback){
  // ???
}

function callback(){
  console.log("Heyo!");
}
```

Is there a Javascript / JQuery solution for this already? If not, how could this be accomplished?

## Edit 1:

Some inspiration for the timing graph itself:

http://easings.net/

## Edit 2:

I'm impressed with you creative folks who have actually used the little ASCII graph I used in the description as an input to the function! I'm looking for a more mathematical solution to this, though...

Here's a better illustration of what I'm thinking. This assumes we're using a quadratic formula (ax^2 + bx + c) over a duration of 20 seconds.

It'd be really cool to pass a function some parameters and have it trigger callbacks at the correct intervals doing something like this:

#### 10 calls over 20 seconds

[image]

#### 20 calls over 20 seconds

[image]

### Edit 3

Some completely untested, back-of-the-napkin pseudocode I'm playing with:

```
function easeTrigger(callback, functionType, functionOptions, duration, numberOfCalls){

    switch("functionType"){
        case "quadratic":
            quadtratic(functionOptions);
            break;
        case "sine":
            sine(functionOptions);
            break;
        /* ... */
        default:
            linear(functionOptions);
            break;
    }

    function quadratic(options){

        var x = numberOfCalls;
        var result;
        var delay;
        var timer;

        for (var i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result = a * Math.pow(x, 2) + (b * x) + c;
            delay = result * 1000; // using the result to calculate the time between function calls
        }

        // ???

        

        for (var s = numberOfCalls - 1; s >= 0; s--) {
            delay = result * 1000; // probably need to chain this somehow, a for loop might not be the best way to go about this.
            timer = setTimeout(result, caller);
        }

        // ???

        // PROFIT!

    }

    function caller(duration){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(delay, callback);
    }

}

// How this might be implemented...

easeTrigger(callback, "quadratic", {a: 1, b: 2, c:0}, 5000, 20);
easeTrigger(callback, "linear", {a: 1, b: 2}, 5000, 10);

// Callback to call at the end of every period

function callback(){
    console.log("Yo!"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use some other external libs?

Comment: External libs are perfectly fine!

It is a nice problem. I might try to solve it without a lib, but a lib would do very nicely for my purposes right now.

Comment: A likely candidate for a lib to handle this functionality: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Would like to test the old grey matter to see if I can't figure out how to do this using only JS, or even JQuery, though...

Answer (score 3):

In the `action` you should set whatever is that you need to do on that curve tick you have mentioned.

```js
function TimeLine(unit, curve, action) {
  this.unit = unit;
  this.curve = curve;
  this.action = action;
  this.tick = 0;

}
TimeLine.prototype.start = function() {
  var me = this;
  console.log('Start.');
  me.id = setInterval(function() {
    me.onRun();
  }, me.unit);
  me.onRun();
};
TimeLine.prototype.stop = function() {
  var me = this;
  console.log('Stop.');
  clearInterval(me.id);
  delete me.id;
};
TimeLine.prototype.onRun = function() {
  var me = this;

  if (me.curve.charAt(me.tick++) === 'o') {
    me.action && me.action();
  } else {
    console.log('Idle...');
  }
  if (me.tick > me.curve.length) {
    me.stop();
  }
}

var log = function() {
    console.log('Ping:', (new Date).getTime());
  },
  t = new TimeLine(200, 'o----o----o--o-o-o-o-ooo', log);

t.start();
```

**EDIT**
Related to your last edit, calculating the intervals some function will be called, some corrections:

So you are seeing the axis of time like this:

```
`t0 -------------- tx --------------------------------------- tN`
```

and you say that on a time interval `duration` (=tN-t0) you will call a function a `numberOfTimes`

so the function will be called in [t0,...,ti,..tx] where x = the `numberOfTimes` and each of these times is calculated with some function

```
function quadratic(options){
    var x = numberOfCalls, 
        delay = 0,
        result, , timer;

    for (var i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result = a * Math.pow(x, 2) + (b * x) + c;
        delay += result * 1000; // cumulate these time values so you can lunch the call already
        // so you call them in a loop but they will start at the precalculated times
        setTimeout(caller, delay);
    }
}
```

This will work though I don t see how you will force the duration to be a specific one, unless it is a parameter of the function somehow.

Comment: Its just me but I'm having trouble reading `me.something`, `me.anotherThing`. I guess, I'm too much used to `self`

Comment: @Rajesh It's just you :) `me` is as good as `self` if not even better, since is only 2 chars instead of 4 and it is not a possible future reserved word ;)

Comment: Very cool implementation, bluehipy. I like the idea of using an actual visual graph... my inner repressed mathematician screams for a mathematical solution somehow, though... maybe with a trig function?

Would love to spend more time thinking about this, but at present I'm trying to ship a feature so I'm going to give it more thought later. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Although I love the inclusion of my actual graph in the implementation, here's an example of how it limits: In your graph, the function is called 10 times in total. What if you wanted to change the threshhold to 20 function calls? You'd need to re-draw the graph.

Comment: you just specify a different `curve` I guess

Comment: @kocyteanIf you can be more specific with what will be the use of it, I could make it more fit for your scope.

Comment: Here's my use case: I'm building a JQuery plugin to do card tricks and sorts. Shuffles, cuts, fanning, etc. I'm adding the option to animate cards one by one, and speed up or slow down how fast the cards are animated... to create a smooth animation for fanning the cards out, or flicking them across the table. The animation is handled by CSS transitions; the only thing I need is to add some CSS styles (positioning, z-index, etc.) at certain intervals.

Comment: @kocytean Fron what you describe the animation is the same so inly the speed changes that is the unit in my implementation. Smaller it us, faster will move.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155123/discussion-between-kocytean-and-bluehipy).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use an external lib, then I would suggest you use a reactive lib like `xstream`. This is typically the kind of problems reactive programming addresses!

There is a great method on observables that allow you to emit things according to a diagram (which is exactly what you have). The method is `fromDiagram`

So in your case, you could do

```
import fromDiagram from 'xstream/extra/fromDiagram'

const stream = fromDiagram('o-o--o---o-----o----------o-----o---o--o-o', {
  timeUnit: 20 // the number of ms, would have to be computed manually
})

stream.addListener({
  next: callback
})
```

The only thing left to do is to compute the `timeUnit` option according to the duration of your animation and the number of steps.

Add to this an object that associate a name of an easing function to a diagram and wrap everything up in a function, and you are good to go :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man, looks very interesting. This is more of a thought experiment now on how to do this kind of thing mathematically, from a curve - I'm not looking to do this generate from a graph, per se. :)

Updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions

- keep function names and signatures identical to the ones from the given example
- no external libraries
- all easing functions have the same signature `f(current time, start value, change in value, duration)`
- invocation rate accuracy can fluctuate within a couple of milliseconds

Google was quick to answer with Flash-era easing equations. I borrowed some from [Robert Penner](http://www.gizma.com/easing/).

```js
const ease = {
  inQuad: (t, b, c, d) => {
    t /= d
    return c * t * t + b
  },
  outQuad: (t, b, c, d) => {
    t /= d
    return -c * t * (t - 2) + b
  }
}

let triggerWithEase = (duration, ease, callback) => {
  const rate = 12 // Lower value makes easing more distinguishable to naked eye
  const totalFrames = Math.floor((duration / 1000) * rate)

  for (let currentFrame = 0; currentFrame < totalFrames; currentFrame += 1) {
    const delay = ease(currentFrame, 0, duration, totalFrames)
    setTimeout(callback, delay)
  }
}

triggerWithEase(
  10000,
  ease.outQuad,
  () => console.log(Date.now())
)
```

**Edit**: Just realised I'm another [Why Can't Programmers Read](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/27/Why_Cant_Programmers._Read.aspx/) example. Made an edit to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

I liked both the question and how it is presented. So just for fun i try to answer in the same fashion.

I have a bunch of easing formulas obtained from [here](http://gizma.com/easing/#l) and applied them for this case.

It's quite simple. I setup the `easing` object to hold all formulas. All radio buttons' `"change"` event listener is assigned with the `drawScale` function. Once the `"change"` event is fired it looks up for the appropriate function and performs it's show. The code is commented so hopefully easier to understand.

It's probably best to watch it working in full screen mode.

```js
function drawScale(e) {

  // inserting span elements at appropriate time
  function insertSpan() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      se = document.createElement("span");
      se.textContent = ">";
      se.classList.add("tick");
      scale.appendChild(se);
    });
  }

  // recursively registers functions at the event looop according to their corresping delay
  // returns setTimeout ids array (stoids) to be cleared if invoked before previous finishes
  function registerSetTimeOut(t, ...ts) {
    return ts.length ? registerSetTimeOut(...ts).concat(setTimeout(insertSpan, t)) :
      [setTimeout(insertSpan, t)];
  }

  var datar = base.map((v, i) => easing[e.currentTarget.value](v, 0, 5000, 5000));
  stoids.forEach(stoid => clearTimeout(stoid)); // clear all awaiting setTimeouts if any
  stoids = []; // resets setTimeout ids array
  stoids = registerSetTimeOut(...datar); // stoids array gets populated with new setTimeout ids

  // clears previously appended span elements at appropriate time
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    while (scale.firstChild) scale.removeChild(scale.firstChild);
  });
}

var easing = {
    "linear": (t, b, c, d) => c * t / d + b,
    "inQuad": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, c * t * t + b),
    "outQuad": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, -c * t * (t - 2) + b),
    "inOutQuad": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? c / 2 * t * t + b : (t--, -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b)),
    "inCubic": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, c * t * t * t + b),
    "outCubic": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, t--, c * (t * t * t + 1) + b),
    "inOutCubic": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? c / 2 * t * t * t + b : (t -= 2, c / 2 * (t * t * t + 2) + b)),
    "inQuart": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, c * t * t * t * t + b),
    "outQuart": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, t--, -c * (t * t * t * t - 1) + b),
    "inOutQuart": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b : (t -= 2, -c / 2 * (t * t * t * t - 2) + b)),
    "inQuint": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, c * t * t * t * t * t + b),
    "outQuint": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, t--, c * (t * t * t * t * t + 1) + b),
    "inOutQuint": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? c / 2 * t * t * t * t * t + b : (t -= 2, c / 2 * (t * t * t * t * t + 2) + b)),
    "inSine": (t, b, c, d) => -c * Math.cos(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + c + b,
    "outSine": (t, b, c, d) => c * Math.sin(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + b,
    "inOutSine": (t, b, c, d) => -c / 2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * t / d) - 1) + b,
    "inExpo": (t, b, c, d) => c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t / d - 1)) + b,
    "outExpo": (t, b, c, d) => c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) + b,
    "inOutExpo": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? c / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b : (t--, c / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t) + 2) + b)),
    "inCirc": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) + b),
    "outCirc": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d, t--, c * Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) + b),
    "inOutCirc": (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d / 2, t < 1 ? -c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) + b : (t -= 2, c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) + 1) + b))
  },
  base = Array.from({
    length: 21
  }).map((_, i) => i * 250),
  stoids = [],
  scale = document.getElementById("scale"),
  radios = document.querySelectorAll('td [type="radio"]');

radios.forEach(r => r.addEventListener("change", drawScale));
```

```css
table {
  width: 33.3vw;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  margin: auto;
}

#scale {
  margin-left: 33vw;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: #d7c0c0;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: #ccc;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

td:nth-child(n+2) {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.desc {
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.tick {
  float:left;
  width: 1.57vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #d7c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Math</th>
      <th>Ease In<span class="desc">Accelerating from zero velocity</span></th>
      <th>Ease Out<span class="desc">Decelerating to zero velocity</span></th>
      <th>Ease In/Out<span class="desc">Acceleration until halfway, then deceleration</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linear</td>
      <td colspan=3><input type="radio" name="math" value="linear"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quadratic</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inQuad"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outQuad"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutQuad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cubic</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inCubic"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outCubic"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutCubic"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quartic</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inQuart"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outQuart"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutQuart"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quintic</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inQuint"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outQuint"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutQuint"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sinusoidal</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inSine"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outSine"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutSine"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exponential</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inExpo"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outExpo"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutExpo"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Circular</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inCirc"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="outCirc"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="math" value="inOutCirc"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="scale"></div>
</div>
```